# MySQL FullText Match

Tags: mysql

I have a table like so:

```
Name    Description
===================
Red     Blue
Blue    Red
Red     Red
```

When I run the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('red')
```

I only get the result with Red in both columns.  How can I make it so that MATCH is an either/or?

It might be how I set up the fulltext indexes, I think I've messed it up somehow.

Comment: `match (name) ... or match (description) ...`? note that if `red` appears too frequently, it'll be considered `noise` by the fulltext system.

Comment: Ahhhhh it's noise that's causing the issue! I wasn't aware of this - thanks for that!